# SQL Comparison Operator in a variable

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query inside a stored procedure where I would like the comparison operator to be a variable.

For instance, here is my SQL query:

```
DECLARE @DueDate dateTime = '2019-11-29'
DECLARE @DueDateOperator varchar = '>'

SELECT * 
FROM someTable 
WHERE dueDate [@DueDateOperator] @DueDate --This doesn't work
```

Is it possible to put a comparison operator in a variable? If not, how can I write this query better such that I can parameterize the comparison operator to anything such as `=` or `<` or `<=` or `>=`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: You could do it with dynamic SQL. But SQL != OOP. There is no shame in writing more than one query

Comment: You shouldn't add a tag `rdbms` to your question - you should add a tag that corresponds to your actual RDBMS used - e.g. `oracle`, `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server` or whatever else you might be using !!

Comment: SQL has no variables. That looks like T-SQL (Microsoft SQL Server)

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like SQL Server.  First, avoid declaring variables with no length.  This is a bug waiting to happen:

```
DECLARE @DueDateOperator varchar = '>';
```

For fun, you can ponder what the result will be if you use `'<>'` or `!='.  *Always* use a length:

```
DECLARE @DueDateOperator varchar(32) = '>';
```

Then, the safest way to handle this would be boolean expressions

```
SELECT * 
FROM someTable 
WHERE (DueDateOperator = '=' AND dueDate = @DueDate) OR
      (DueDateOperator = '<>' AND dueDate <> @DueDate) OR
      (DueDateOperator = '<' AND dueDate < @DueDate) OR
      (DueDateOperator = '<=' AND dueDate <= @DueDate) OR
      (DueDateOperator = '>' AND dueDate > @DueDate) OR
      (DueDateOperator = '>=' AND dueDate >= @DueDate) ;
```

This prevents any form of SQL injection.

Finally, you can only replace constant values in a string using parameters.  If you want to replace an operator (or keyword or function name or table name and so forth), you have to munge the query string.  This is unsafe, because it can open the way to SQL injection attacks.  But the method would be:

```
declare @DueDate dateTime = '2019-11-29';
declare @DueDateOperator varchar(32) = '>';
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
select *
from sometable
where dueDate @DueDateOperator @DueDate';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '@DueDateOperator', @DueDateOperator);

exec sp_executesql @sql,
                   N'@DueDate datetime',
                   @DueDate @DueDate;
```

Although you cannot pass the operator in as a parameter in dynamic SQL, you can pass the constant value.  This uses `sp_executesql` which allows the passing of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, try this:

```
    Declare @DueDate dateTime = '2019-11-29'
    Declare @DueDateOperator varchar = '>'
    Declare @sql Nvarchar(MAX) = ''
    Set  @sql = 'Select * from someTable where dueDate ' + @DueDateOperator +  ' '''+ convert(varchar, @DueDate, 23) +  ''' '
    EXECUTE (@sql )

--print  ( @sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL as below:

```
DECLARE @DueDate dateTime = '2019-11-29'
DECLARE @DueDateOperator varchar = '>'
DECLARE @Cmd NVARCHAR(4000) = 'SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE dueDate ' + @DueDateOperator + ''''  + CONVERT( NVARCHAR(10), @DueDate , 23)   + '''' 

SELECT @Cmd

EXECUTE(@Cmd)
```